Could not find a configuration file for package "Protobuf" that is compatible with requested version "3.1.0"
I'm trying to fork an old program, and I used CMake to grab the necessary dependencies. Here's the thing: when loading up the project folder, I get the error:

Could not find a configuration file for package "Protobuf" that is compatible with requested version "3.1.0".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

  E:/GoldbergDevelopment/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows-static/share/protobuf/protobuf-config.cmake, version: 25.1.0

I assume that this means I should install version 3.1.0 of Protobuf, but vcpkg doesn't allow installing specific versions of packages with the command line and following this tutorial just gives me the following error:
-- Running vcpkg install
error: failed to execute: "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" --git-dir=.git "--work-tree=E:\GoldbergDevelopment\vcpkg\buildtrees\versioning_\versions\protobuf\356bda3330a44573c612a81d53e53994db01fda1_7668.tmp" -c core.autocrlf=false read-tree -m -u 356bda3330a44573c612a81d53e53994db01fda1
error: git failed with exit code: (128).
fatal: not a git repository: '.git'
note: while checking out port protobuf with git tree 356bda3330a44573c612a81d53e53994db01fda1
error: while checking out baseline from commit 'c7a7d062a750bce13a9db3fa8af5018d38554565', failed to `git show` versions/baseline.json. This may be fixed by fetching commits with `git fetch`.
error: git failed with exit code: (128).
fatal: not a git repository: '.git'
while checking out baseline c7a7d062a750bce13a9db3fa8af5018d38554565
-- Running vcpkg install - failed
CMake Error at E:/GoldbergDevelopment/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:902 (message):
  vcpkg install failed.  See logs for more information:
  E:\GoldbergDevelopment\protobuf_installing\build\vcpkg-manifest-install.log
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:146 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

This is my vcpkg.json, by the way:
{
  "dependencies": [ "fmt", "protobuf" ],
  "builtin-baseline": "c7a7d062a750bce13a9db3fa8af5018d38554565",
  "overrides": [
    { 
        "name": "protobuf", 
        "version": "3.2.0"
    }
  ]
}

Any ideas what to do next?

I expect the problem is here: error: git failed with exit code: (128).
